# Difference in different application opening and workspace

Tags: 20.04, gnome, unity, workspaces

I have 2 questions related to launching applications Ubuntu 20.04.

1. When opening system applications like gnome-terminal, if another application or window is focused then the opening window is opened in the background with a notification about it. But if a non-system application like a web browser or code-editor like vscode is opened like this, then it opens in the foreground and thus disturbing the workflow. **Can I change this behaviour of applications?**
2. If I switch to a new workspace and quickly open an application and switch back to the previous workspace before the application window opens, then the application window opens in whichever workspace I am currently in, instead of opening in the workspace where it was called. **Is this a bug or this kind of feature is not implemented yet?**

Comment: I don't know about the 1st one but 2nd one is a bug that is really irritating, It is not in Ubuntu 21.10 BTW.

Comment: @AkshajSingla glad to hear that, but is there any extension or something to prevent this in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Extensions are not created to fix bugs.  Devs need to know about bugs so they can fix them.  Please [file a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: When you discover an application that hijacks focus, that's usually also a bug.

Comment: Better to ask one question at one time here. 2) also happens on 21.10. A window is created on the current workspace. 1) indeed is inconsistent and inpredictable. There is an extension no-annoyance to always launch and get focus, but not the other way round. There is unfortunately on the Linux desktop no control on how to launch an application (e.g. minimized).

Comment: okay, so the only way is bug reporting which will hopefully fix these things in the upcoming 22.04. thanks, @vanadium user535733 and Nmath

Comment: there are bug reports on both of these issues https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/962471 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/455241, but the 2nd bug report is really old